# How do I get next month in php in a specific format?

Tags: php, date, date-format

I want to get the next month, like this:

If current month is 5 next month will be 6 **OR** If current month is 12 next month will 1.

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$d = new DateTime($current_date);
$next_month = $d->modify( 'next month' );
```

Now I am getting this:

```
object(DateTime)#69 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-04-26 00:00:00"
```

Comment: That looks like what you should be expecting. What's your actual question/problem?

Comment: I want the output to be a digit. If current month is march the output should be 4 not object(DateTime)#69 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2015-04-26 00:00:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `DateTime::format()` to format the output. Specifically use the `n` flag:

```
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$d = new DateTime($current_date);
$next_month = $d->modify( 'next month' );
echo $next_moth->format('n');
```